# What am I doing wrong here exactly?

Tags: c, loops, fibonacci

I'm writing a program to identify if the entered number from the user is a Fibonacci number. The program runs fine and it does what it needs to do, but I'm trying to make the program say that it isn't a Fibonacci number when the user enters a number that isn't one, it's not working, and I'm not sure on what I need to adjust.

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    int flag = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int NextTerm;
   
    printf("this is a program to determine if a number is a Fibonacci number\n");
    printf("please enter your number\n");
    printf("the number you entered is : ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
   
    while (true) {
        NextTerm = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = NextTerm;
        if (a == number) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
      
    if (flag == 1) {
        printf("The number you entered which is %d is a Fibonacci Number\n", number);
    } else
    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("The number you entered which is %d is not a Fibonacci Number\n", number);
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You also need to `break` the loop when the `NextTerm` is bigger than the number entered by the user.

Comment: By not working do you mean you're stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: Your should Indent your code properly so it is readable. Readable code makes it easier to find bugs in your code. And name your variables properly. Why call it `flag` when you can call it `isFibonacciNumber`?

Comment: no ,i mean stuck as in it doesnt print when a number isnt a Fibonacci number,loop works fine

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry im still a beginner programmer

Comment: @blake don't be sorry but improve your code instead.

Comment: Hint: add `printf("%d\n", a);` right after `b=NextTerm;` and you'll understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Hint 2: additionally replace `while (true)` with `int i = 0; while (i++ < 25)` in order to stop your loop after 25 iterations.

Comment: @Jabberwocky but why would i want to limit the range?wouldn't this mean that the program wont check if the 26,27,....Nth term are Fibonacci numbers or not ?

Comment: @blake the `printf` is just for debugging, and so is limiting the range, otherwise the printed numbers will be scrolled too quickly out of your sight and you won't see anything interesting

Comment: You should stop the iteration when `(a >= number)` not when `(a == number)`. Otherwise if it is not a F number the iteration will never stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you do not stop the loop when `a`, the current Fibonacci number, becomes larger than `number`. Hence you continue enumerating the Fibonacci numbers until `a + b` causes an arithmetic overflow, at which point your program has undefined behavior. On current systems, the loop continues modulo 2<sup>32</sup> until you reach a value of `a` that will match `number`. Whether this loop actually stops is an interesting but separate question, yet the result will be incorrect as `flag` will have been set to `1` if the loop ever stops.

To fix the problem, you could just add `if (a > number) break;` at the end of the `while` loop's body.

Note that you should test `b` instead of `a` to avoid report `0` as a Fibonacci number.

Here is a simplified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
   
    printf("This is a program to determine if a number is a Fibonacci number\n");
    printf("please enter your number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1)
        return 1;
   
    while (b < number) {
        int NextTerm = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = NextTerm;
    }
      
    if (b == number) {
        printf("The number you entered which is %d is a Fibonacci Number\n", number);
    } else {
        printf("The number you entered which is %d is not a Fibonacci Number\n", number);
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```